# IntelliJ Artifact has invalid extension

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, jboss7.x

I have strange a problem with deploying an artifact on jboss. After generating the default spring-mvc project in IntelliJ, I tried to run it, but IntelliJ showed in "Run/Debug Configuration" a message that my "Artifact XYZ:war exploded has invalid extension".

I found advice on stackoverflow "change extension" but I have correct `.war` extension.

What is wrong?

Comment: I think your exploded directory should have a name ending with '.war' (the directory, not the actual war).

Comment: Thanks Nebelmann, it works fine.

Comment: same tip worked for me also, but every time i change pom.xml it reverts back that directory name. Does anyone have a better workaround?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simply add .war to your output directory name.
[image: Add .war extension at the right place]

Unfortunately changing the `pom.xml` with Maven will probably result into a modification of the output directory, and you will have to do it again.

Comment: I got tired of editing this after every tiny change to the pom.xml, until I stumbled on a more permanent fix which I describe here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27612488/318912

Comment: You saved my day

Answer (score 4):

There is a [bug report](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-86484) that's over two years old.  Still hasn't been resolved.  [Here is another bug report](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-95162), also two years old, that's marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

This is the bug in IntelliJ. It does not support upper case on Artifact.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open module settings (F4 on your project)
2. Go to artifacts
3. make sure that Output directory points to folder with suffix ".war"

   XXsomewar_exploded.war

If not, just delete all artifacts with red minus sign, and click then plus sign and select war exploaded. Then also select Build on make checkbox

Go also to your project on disk, and check folder out, if it containes exploaded war folder and if stuff is inside.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the artifact to be deployed from exploded to war in server configuration and it worked fine for me