# Intellij IDEA artifact 'XXXX:war exploded' has invalid extension

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, java-ee-7, intellij-13

Every time I make even the tiniest change to my POM Intellij removes the .war extension for my *exploded* artifact in the Project Structure output directory setting. This causes an error in Intellij's Run/Debug configuration:

**Artifact 'XXXX:war exploded' has invalid extension.**

In order to resolve the issue I must manually override the Project Structure output directory setting. Every time I make even the tiniest change to the POM I must go back to the Output directory setting and manually append ".war" to the end of the Output directory setting.  This is getting very old and frustrating.

e.g. I must change this:

E:\workarea\enterp\application\target\application

to this:

E:\workarea\enterp\application\target\application.war

If I manually set the Maven WAR plugin outputDirectory configuration as follows, this does not help at all:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>

        <!-- Output directory of artifact:war exploded keeps losing the .war extension -->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}.war</outputDirectory>

    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How can I resolve this problem?

**EDIT:**

Here's the complete build config:

```
    <build>
    <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name
        given to the generated war, and hence the context root) -->
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <!-- Compiler plugin enforces Java 1.6 compatibility and activates annotation
            processors -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Output directory of artifact:war exploded keeps losing the .war extension -->
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.war</outputDirectory>

                <!-- Java EE 7 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- The WildFly plugin deploys your war to a local WildFly container -->
        <!-- To use, run: mvn package wildfly:deploy -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

**SECOND EDIT:**

I discovered that one solution is to append ".war" to ${project.artifactId} in the build configuration, e.g.:

```
<finalName>${project.artifactId}.war</finalName>
```

and remove outputDirectory from the plugin configuration.  So the build config should look like this:

```
<build>
    <!--
        Maven will make finalName the name of the generated war.

        NOTE:   Output directory of artifact:war exploded keeps losing the .war extension
                http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-86484
                http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-95162

                The solution is to append ".war" to ${project.artifactId}, below:
    -->
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}.war</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <!-- Compiler plugin enforces Java 1.6 compatibility and activates annotation
            processors -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Java EE 7 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- The WildFly plugin deploys your war to a local WildFly container -->
        <!-- To use, run: mvn package wildfly:deploy -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

DISCLAIMER:  If you use this workaround just be aware that when you deploy an unexploded WAR artifact the file name will be named XXXX.war.war.  It works -- I deployed the artifact as a WAR file in Intellij -- but it's ugly.

> INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "XXXX.war.war" (runtime-name: "XXXX.war.war)"

If someone can tell me how to configure the Intellij project to work with Maven to select one or the other finalName values depending on whether I'm deploying a WAR file vs. exploded artifact then this question will be sufficiently answered.

```
<!-- Exploded artifact --> 
<finalName>${project.artifactId}.war</finalName>

<!-- WAR file (unexploded) artifact --> 
<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
```

Comment: Why are you changing the finalName in the pom.xml? Are you doing that to work around this bug, or for some other reason related to your development/deployment workflow?

Answer (score 36):

There's a way to fix this in IntelliJ, without changing your pom.xml file(s), by adding an artifact with a reference to the exploded war (or in my case, the exploded ear) and it won't get stomped every time IntelliJ re-imports the maven pom(s). Here's how:

1. Stop/undeploy your current artifact deployment
2. Edit your run config, and in the Deployment tab, remove the current exploded war/ear artifact
3. Open the project's Artifacts settings and add a new artifact
   [image: Add new artifact]
4. Use the plus button to add a new war or (in my case) ear exploded artifact
   [image: Add new war or ear exploded artifact]
5. Give it a name, then edit the Output directory to add the appropriate extension (.war or .ear)
   [image: Rename output directory to add extension]
6. In the Output Layout section where you see `<output root>`, use the plus button to add an Artifact
   [image: Add new artifact in output layout]
7. Select the desired exploded artifact
   [image: Select the desired exploded artifact]
8. Edit your run config again, and in the Deployment tab, add the new workaround exploded artifact
   [image: Deploy new artifact in run configuration]

Thanks to Nikolay Chashnikov for describing this in his comment on the [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-86484)

Comment: When using Maven (modify step 5 above) move the IDEA -> Project Structure -> ear:ear exploded -> Output directory, down a level. This is because Maven clean/package expects the target\groupId.artifactId-version.ear to always be a file. So in IDEA set something like "C:\Project\ear\target\idea\groupId.artifactId-version.ear" note the addition of "\idea\" in the path as well as .ear suffix to the directory name, now no conflict with simultaneous maven clean/package cycles.

Comment: This is by far the easiest and safest solution. Thanks, Alex!

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you should leave the `finalName` attribute alone, otherwise you'll get the problems you describe. Rather, you should change the config for the maven war plugin to use the `webappDirectory` like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.${project.packaging}</webappDirectory>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: If this was the solution it would be a very poor solution because if I choose to deploy using the non-exploded WAR artifact then I do not want to deploy to ${project.build.directory}.war. However, I attempted to use this configuration setting to see if it would make a difference. It did not. The problem for WAR exploded artifact did not go away.

Comment: Fyi the Intellij bug report is [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-86484).

Comment: this configuration worked for me. I guess profiles can be used to change the directory according to needs to overcome @PatrickGarner 's concerns

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking about WAR inside EAR there is another way to resolve your problem by using correct configuration inside maven-ear-plugin. WAR pom.xml should be left as is, without any changes, but EAR pom.xml should contains something like this. (please, pay your attention to  **<unpack>${unpack.wars}</unpack>**)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <version>6</version>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
        <generateApplicationXml>false</generateApplicationXml>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <modules>
            <webModule>
                <groupId>com.test.app</groupId>
                <artifactId>test-app-war</artifactId>
                <unpack>${unpack.wars}</unpack>
            </webModule>
        </modules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and then you can add profiles **default** and **debug** for proper artifact assembling.

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <unpack.wars>false</unpack.wars>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>debug</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>debug</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <unpack.wars>true</unpack.wars>
            </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

use **debug** profile inside IntelliJ IDEA for expanding wars and **default** profile for building artifacts in command line or CI (default profile would be active if no profile were provided, so your build will works as previously).

[image: Maven Projects view]

With this solution HotSwap and resources updates works as expected.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's the same as this question: [IntelliJ Artifact has invalid extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678910/intellij-artifact-has-invalid-extension)

Add a .war extension to the output directory as shown in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25569266/968988

Comment: The problem is that Project Structure keeps losing the .war extension added to output directory name every time the POM is edited.  It's a bug.  Check my [earlier answer to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24725489).